# CORS error while using Nest.js and server side rendered Angular Universal app

Tags: angular, cors, nestjs, angular-universal

I have a server side rendered Angular Universal app using Nest.js. So they are running on the same origin, localhost:4200.

I have tried enabling CORS (with various cors-options) in the Nest.js app using:

```
async function bootstrap() {
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.enableCors(
  {
    origin: false,
    preflightContinue: true,
    methods: ['GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT'],
  }
)
app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
await app.listen(process.env['PORT'] || 4000);
```

}

Tried setting origin to: http://localhost:4200 without any success.

Also tried the simpler without success:

```
app.enableCors()
```

I'm getting the following errors in the web console:

Origin http://localhost:4200 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/ due to access control checks.
Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:4200 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200 ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com), line 0)

I'm simply trying to do a GET request using Angular HttpClient in my front-end:

```
  public fetchData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get('https://www.google.com')
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `origin: false` means that no origin is allowed. Try `origin: "http://localhost:4200"` instead.

Comment: Tried that one as well but didn’t work

Comment: Actually, scratch that; I misread your question. Because `https://www.google.com` simply is not configured for CORS, you cannot access this resource from client code.

Comment: Added that to the question itself to make it more clear that I already tried it as well

Comment: What are you referring to by "I already tried it" in your latest comment? There's nothing you can do to consume the resource that lives at `https://www.google.com` from your client. Your only option is to consume it from your backend and proxy that to your client.

Comment: @jub0bs meant that I already tried to set origin to: http://localhost:4200 as suggested by first post. Yes, currently proxying using my backend just as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are properly enabling CORS in your backend, that means that client can make API requests to your backend from different origin than the backend's without the browser blocking the result.

yet in your question, you are making requests from you frontend (which is assume was served from the backend's origin) to a different origin - google's.
that means that google's backend is the one who needs to be configuring CORS, yet the endpoint you requested does not allow cross-origin and the request fails.

to summary, even tho you have configured CORS on your backend, you are making request to a different backend which didn't allow CORS.
because you have configured CORS on your backend, means that clients from different origin will successfully be able to make requests to your backend.
you can verify that if you run the same script on different ports and make request from a client that was served from lets say port `4000` to backend that runs on port `4001`.

as suggested in the comments, to solve this issue specifically you need to proxy the request to `google` in your backend (which doesn't have the browser's CORS policy). in this way you will send an API call from your frontend to your backend which in turn will send the request to google and will return the result to your frontend.